# Summing across many sheets with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using this formula to sum across many sheets, which works fine:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Table1[List1]&"'!$F$6:F$9"),INDIRECT("'"&Table1[List1]&"'!A$6:A$9"),$A8))
```

However, I need to add another criteria to the sum. I need it to sum only if the sheet contains a specific word in cell `A1`. I have 150 sheets and each contains either `XX` or `YY` in `A1`.

So in the end I would have two formulas: one that sums if `A1` contains `XX`, and one that sums if `A1` contains `YY`.

Tried tweaking the formula but keep getting errors

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Table1[List1]&"'!A1"),"xx"),SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Table1[List1]&"'!$F$6:F$9"),INDIRECT("'"&Table1[List1]&"'!A$6:A$9"),$A8))
```

Hope this helps!